# appending data to a file in php error

Tags: php

The following code reads data from a file into a series of arrays, as well as data from another webpage, compares the data based on the value from the form and the arrays, and if no match is found, appends the data to the file

```
<?php
$file = fopen("Student.txt", "a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$StudentID = array();
$StudentPassword = array();
$StudentFname = array();
$StudentLname = array();
$StudentDOB = array();
$StudentGPA = array();
$x = 0;
$return = 0;

while(!feof($file)){
  $StudentID[$x] = fgets($file);
  $StudentPassword[$x] = fgets($file);
  $StudentFname[$x] = fgets($file);
  $StudentLname[$x] = fgets($file);
  $StudentDOB[$x] = fgets($file);
  $StudentGPA[$x] = fgets($file);
  $x = $x + 1;
  }

  $ID = $_POST["StudentID"];
  $Pass = $_POST["StudentPass"];
  $First = $_POST["StudentFname"];
  $last = $_POST["StudentLname"];
  $DOB = $_POST["D.O.B."];
  $GPA = $_POST["GPA"];

  for ($y=0; $y<$x; $y++){
    if (strcasecmp($ID,$StudentID[$y]) == -2){
    $return = 1;
    break;
  }
  }
  if ($return == 0){
      echo $ID "<br>";
      fputs($ile, $ID);
      fputs($file, $Pass);
      echo $First "<br>";
      fputs($file, $First);
      echo $last <"br>";
      fputs($file, $last);
      echo $DOB "<br>";
      fputs($file, $DOB);
      echo $GPA "<br>";
      fputs($file, $GPA);

      echo "Student successfully added";
 }
  else{
      echo "Duplicate ID found, input rejected";
  }
  fclose($file);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Student Addition</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Please return to the <a href ="index.html">Main Menu</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything works except for the last part. If there is no match found, its supposed to append the data, but as it stands, the append part doesn't append the data to the file, leaving it as it is. If anyone may know why this is the case, your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried changing the variable $return to $result for example because return is a reserved word.

Comment: I used $result instead of $return, and got a code error where your screen doesn't show up. I'll have to assume its not that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `0` instead of `-2` as as result value for `strcasecmp()`, because 0 means there is a match and in your case if there is a match it should not be added.

```
for ($y=0; $y<$x; $y++){
  if (strcasecmp($ID,$StudentID[$y]) == 0){
  $return = 1;
  break;
 }
}
```

See [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp)

Comment: its not an error with the values anymore, its an error in the fact that its not printing it to the file period, whether data is accepted or not. That's the problem being experienced, if its any help